# How to store the result of each iteration of a for loop into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Score Finder (100 Marks)

Praveen is finding a job as a Computer Science teacher in school. 
He has been rejected many times by different schools but this time he is determined to get the job. 
He goes to the principal of the school St. Mary.

The principal says that in his school there is Grading and Credit system.
There are N subjects and each subject has a credit Ci attached to it (1 <= i <= N). 
Each student gets a particular grade in each subject and each grade has a point value which are:

```
A = 10, 
A(minus) = 9, 
B = 8, 
B(minus) = 7, 
C = 6, 
C(minus) = 5
```

Now if there are 3 subjects of credits 4, 3 and 2 respectively and a particular student scores A(minus), 
B and C in these 3 subjects respectively then his score would be calculated as follows:
Total Score=Summation of product of Grade point and corresponding credit for each subject.

```
= ( (9*4) + (3*8) + (2*6) ) = 72.
```

He wants Praveen to tell total distinct Scores that are possible 
to be given to a student given credits of N subjects by assigning different grades to each subject.

Input Format
Your function contains a single argument- a one-dimensional Integer Array A of N elements where each represents Credit of that subject.
The first line of input contains an Integer N denoting the size of the array.
Next N lines of input each containing an Integer denoting the credit Ci of ith subject

```
Constraints
1 <= N <= 100
1 <= Ci <= 5
```

Output Format
You must return a single integer denoting the total number of scores that are possible to be given.

```
Sample TestCase 1
Input

2
1
2
Output

16
```

now I am writing code like this

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CandidateCode {
    private static void possibleCombination(int input) {
        int i=0;
        int[] a=new int[Grades.length];

        a[i]=input;
        System.out.println("the a is "+a[i]);
    }

    private static final int[] Grades = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0,j,totalSummation=0;
        Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter length of Array:");
        int index = uInput.nextInt();
        int[] Credit = new int[index];
        for (i = 0; i <= Credit.length-1; i++) {
            Credit[i] = uInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println("credit is" + Credit[i]);
            for ( j = 0; j <= Grades.length - 1; j++) {
                totalSummation = +(Grades[j] * Credit[i]);
                possibleCombination(totalSummation);
                // System.out.println("total sum is " + totalSummation);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Now I want to store the values calculated in each iteration...
Meaning for 
iteration first the values are 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 
itertion second the values are 20,18,16,14,10,8,6,4,2

i want to sum each value of 1st iteration with all the values of 2nd iteration.
i,e 10+20, 10+18, 10+16, 10+14, 10+10, 10+8, 10+6, 10+4, 10+2
similarly for 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

To achieve this I need to store the values per iteration but I am stuck here, please guys help me to get rid of this problem thank you in advance.

Comment: You have two for loops. I understand that you want to store values per iteration of the second. A possible solution is to use a multidimensional array (array[][]). Declared before the first loop. A second one is declared in the first loop : Each iteration the second loop stores item in the second array. After each second loop, you store this array in the first
It will result an array, containing arrays that represent values of your second for loop.
EDIT : after reading my comment i'm not sure it is easily understandable, if you want i'll make a more detailed answer

Comment: I agreed to you polu ..but the challenge is to achieve the same by using one dimensional array :-(

Comment: Its your pleasure if you provide more detailed explanation..in addition the output can be anything between 1 to 100, so we need a code who works and pass all the test cases

Comment: Ok i didn't understood this part of the challenge. So you want the sum of credit * grades ?
Can we assume that grades and credit have the same cardinality ?

Comment: yessss, both have same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    public class Sample {
        public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int nValue = scan.nextInt();
            if(nValue<1 || nValue>100){
                System.out.println("Array Value cannot be less than 1 or greater than 100");
            }
            int[] inputCredits = new int[nValue];
            for( int i=0 ; i < nValue ; i++){
                inputCredits[i]=scan.nextInt();
                if(inputCredits[i]<1 || inputCredits[i]>5){
                    System.out.println("Credit Value cannot be less than 1 or greater than 5");
                }
            }
            List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.stream(inputCredits).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8,9,10);
//checked for basic constraints up till this point
//Next what we multiply all the inputted Credits with the possible grades and 
// store in the list where x input Credits will produce a list of x*6 entries 
// where first six entries are the possibilities for the first Credit, next 6 
// entries for the 2nd credit and so on, having this knowledge we loop through // the list to get all the possible scores 
            List<Integer> permutedList = list1.stream().flatMap(i -> list2.stream().map(j -> i*j)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<Integer> listForDistinctSet= new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0; i<6 ; i++){
                listForDistinctSet.add(permutedList.get(i));
            }
            Set<Integer> distinctSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

            for(int j=6,k=j+6;k<=permutedList.size();j=k,k=k+6){
                Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
                for(int i=0; i<listForDistinctSet.size(); i++){

                    for(; j<k ; j++){
                        int sum = listForDistinctSet.get(i) + permutedList.get(j);
                        newSet.add(sum);
                    }
                    j=k-6;
                }
                distinctSet=newSet;
                listForDistinctSet = new ArrayList<>(distinctSet);
            }
            System.out.println(distinctSet.size());

       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code does and how it works to solve the OPs problem?

Comment: @udaya Thank you so much kiran ..perfectly pass all test cases

Comment: @Al0x : added comments to the code to explain what it does

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store in a multi-dimensional array then you need to store each iteration in single dimensional array as below. But this code will work only for two credits.

```
public class CandidateCode {

        private static int possibleCombination(int input)
        {   int i=0;
            int[] a=new int[Grades.length];
             a[i]=input;
              return a[i];

        }
        private static final int[] Grades = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 
                           3, 2, 1};

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int i=0,j,totalSummation=0;
            Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter length of Array:");
            int index = uInput.nextInt();             
            int[] Credit = new int[index];
            int[] creditarr = new int[10];
            int[] credit1 = new int[10];
            int[] credit2 = new int[10];
            for (i = 0; i <= Credit.length-1; i++) {
                Credit[i] = uInput.nextInt();

                System.out.println("credit is" + Credit[i]);
                for ( j = 0; j <= Grades.length - 1; j++) {
                    totalSummation = +(Grades[j] * Credit[i]);
                     creditarr[j]=possibleCombination(totalSummation);
                     if(Credit[i]==1) {
                     credit1[j]=creditarr[j];  
                     }
                     if(Credit[i]==2){
                     credit2[j]=creditarr[j];
                     }
                    }
                }

            for(int k=0;k<credit1.length;k++) {
                for(int l=0;l<credit2.length;l++) {
                    int final_no=credit1[k]+credit2[l];
                    System.out.println("final_no :"  +final_no);
                }
            }
            }

         }
```

Is this what you want?

I guess the below code would be the best solution.This code will work for the no of credits you mention.

```
public class Candidate {
 private static final int[] Grades = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0,score=0,totalsummation=0;
    Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter length of Array:");
    int arraylength = uInput.nextInt();             
    int[] credits= new int[arraylength];
    ArrayList<Integer> combination = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (i = 0; i <credits.length; i++) {
        credits[i] = uInput.nextInt();  
    }
    switch(credits.length) {
    case 1:
        for(int c1=10;c1>=5;c1--) {
            totalsummation = c1*credits[0];
            combination.add(totalsummation);
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        for(int g:Grades) {
            for(int c2=10;c2>=5;c2--) {
                totalsummation=g*credits[0]+c2*credits[1];
                combination.add(totalsummation);
            }
        }
        break;

    case 3:
            for(int g:Grades) {
            for(int c3=10;c3>=5;c3--) {
                totalsummation=g*credits[0]+c3*credits[1]+c3*credits[2];
                combination.add(totalsummation);
            }
        }
            break;
    case 4:
        for(int g:Grades) {
            for(int c4=10;c4>=5;c4--) {
                totalsummation=g*credits[0]+c4*credits[1]+c4*credits[2]+c4*credits[3];
                combination.add(totalsummation);    
            }
        }
        break;

    case 5:
        for(int g:Grades) {
            for(int c5=10;c5>=5;c5--) {
                totalsummation=g*credits[0]+c5*credits[1]+c5*credits[2]+c5*credits[3]+c5*credits[4];
                combination.add(totalsummation);
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }



 ArrayList<Integer> distinctnos =(ArrayList<Integer>) combination.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
     System.out.println(distinctnos.size());            }
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Dora, that is i want, now from here I need to filter out the distinct value which is the total permutation r number of ways to assign credit  to each subject

Comment: but what for 1 2 3 or more is this code is efficient to handle 3+ values

Comment: according to your solution we need 5 more arrays, which is not good practice, can we have optimal solution who work independently for any credit value

Comment: Yes.. I agree that's not the optimal solution but u wanted to write program only in single dimensional array not to use multi-dimensional array, that's why I had given that solution. U can save all that iteration in a single array also and do the operation u want but I didn't want to confuse you that's why I had written 2 separate arrays for each credit. Moreover I'm not sure why are u getting size of array separately and credits separately.. you can take single input from the user.. there's no need of credit array in your program? Is it mandatory to get input in that mentioned format?

Comment: I have updated my answer above with the new code. You can check. You can still avoid the credit array for getting the inputs if that's not mandatory. And note, here you will not have all the iteration values in the creditarr array. your array will have only the final values.

Comment: Thank you Dora for quick response, yeah actually we need to maintain an array to take input from user, if you read problem statement, they clearly mentioned that credit also represent no. of subjects too and only 6 specific grades are need to assign, if you still confuse i suggest you to read the problem statement.

Comment: one more thing your latest solution is not producing required output.it add (iteration 1's first value)+(iteration 2nd first value) ONLY

Comment: I'm getting the expected result. I have updated my output also now. You can try once again. You might have missed something while copying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160501/discussion-between-zia-and-dora).

Comment: i am not getting the same :-(

Comment: i am getting 30
27
24
21
18
15

Comment: @Zia - What's wrong with my answer? May I know the reason why my answer was rejected after its accepted? Didn't u say that my code was working fine for you? Then why it was rejected??

Answer (score -2):

Ok, following our discussion in comments: you don't need two for loops.

```
for i = 0; i < array.size(); i++ {
    sum += grade[i]*credit[i]
 }
```

Sorry for the generic coding style. Is it what you want?

Comment: Initializing sum to 0 before the loop, you iterate through the two array at the same time, summing what you want

Comment: sum +=  grade[i]*credit[i]; you just need that not sum twice and a semicolon

Comment: i want to store values for first iteration i,e 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 now i want these values in an array...now iteration no.II, i have now 20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,4,2...... now the next task is addition take 10 and add with all the values of 2nd iteration values..take 9 and add with all the values of 2nd iteration

Comment: Please add the missing `(` `)` and the missing initialization. and size is length. Do you know that this is a java question?

Comment: @Clijsters I know, thanks. However it appears to me that the the problem isn't related to java, nor the solution. That's why my answer is about algorithm, not java. If it was a java error or something from java that wasn't understood, i would have written java. ;)

Comment: The problem however is tagged with [tag:java] and you didn't mention that your code example shouldn't be valid java code. Please consider [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)

Comment: I mentionned it was a generic coding style, and this answer come after a discussion with the author in comments. But I get what you said. I indeed dislike when giving the entire solution, and thought it will be better to show him  the way. I'll try to add more explanation next time !